# A pervasive, consistent, .... root-soil net?

Tags: word-choice

I am translating a technical book on agriculture, despairing over the German phrase "ein durchgängiges Wurzel-Erde-Netz," meaning soil that is alive will form a root-soil net that pervades every corner of the ground under the plant. Can I translate that into "forming a **pervasive** root-soil net" or "a **consistent** root-soil net," or what other adjective would you suggest? And would you hyphenate root-soil net?

EDIT: How about "**a root-soil network completely pervading the spade sample**"? (a spade sample being a piece of soil dug out from a growing field; spade samples play a central role in the context of the phrase I need to translate)

Comment: Hi. I think "root network" is probably what you are looking for.  Pervasive is often used in a negative sense in English.  If you don't want a negative meaning, then perhaps "well developed" would be better.

Comment: Please elaborate on what the hyphens imply in the original German. Are they present in the original?  root-soil-net is not immediately clear.  A network of roots in soil? A synergy of root and soil?

Comment: Hello back, thanks for both your replies. True, "network" sounds better than just "net." As for "pervasive" I had thought the same, i.e., as having a negative ring to it. The hyphens used in the German phrase are mandatory; they function to form the 3-part compound in this case. A (lesser legible) variant would be "Wurzelerdenetz". The English version, something tells me, does not need a hyphen at all because I have learned you only need it to combine different parts of speech, which is not the case in "root soil network," am I right?

Comment: How about "comprehensive"? wiktionary says "Broadly or completely covering; including a large proportion of something."

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Sam, but, doesn't "comprehensive" have an abstract meaning? What would you think of "a root soil network reaching all the way through the dig-out," referring to a soil sample dug out with a spade.

Comment: "dig-out" looks like a fake made-up word. In your question, I don't see the original German where that particular word is coming from. How about "excavation". Yes, maybe "comprehensive" is often used abstractly,  but here it could be used more literally, and it seems to be a nice artistic choice to do so. Just an idea.

Comment: This is the context of the phrase I am trying to translate:                                
 "– auf dem Spaten sieht der Bodenausstich zusammenhängend wie 
Pudding aus
– ein durchgängiges Wurzel-Erde-Netz (ist zu sehen)

Comment: And what about "spade sample" instead of "dig-out" or "excavation"?

Comment: Only if "spade sample" is actual technical jargon in that specific field of science. Maybe it is, need to check.  Google Translate for the whole sentence suggests "continuous".  Pretty good!  I would switch "spade" to "shovel" and use their results.

Comment: Thanks, Sam! "Spade sample," at least in the German version "Spatenprobe," is a new word because the whole concept of taking spade samples is new in agriculture.

Comment: It is actually a spade that is used for it, not a shovel.

Comment: root-soil is not accurate: https://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/42259/Rhizosphere.pdf

Comment: Also: The rhizosphere is the narrow region of soil or substrate that is directly influenced by root secretions and associated soil microorganisms known as the root microbiome. Wikipedia

Comment: For technical translation, it is a good idea to go and find similar texts in order to find the vocabulary and not just rely on dictionaries, monolingual or bilingual.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are translating, but literally translating "ein durchgängiges Wurzel-Erde-Netz" gives us something like: "a continuous root-soil-network".

You've given the additional clarification, "soil that is alive will form a root-soil net that pervades every corner of the ground under the plant."

Given that context, I would be tempted to render it something like, **"a pervasive root-soil ecosystem"**.

I prefer "ecosystem" to "network" since I think it better captures the living, symbiotic nature.

Unlike other commenters, I do not think "pervasive" has a negative connotation in English - it simply means "everywhere". However, if you are concerned, you could use a word like "ubiquitous" or "extensive".

Depending on your flexibility in rendering the translation more figuratively, you might consider adding "vibrant" to the translation: **"a vibrant, pervasive root-soil ecosystem"**

**UPDATE: a few hours later**

After thinking about it, I would go with a looser, but smoother, English rendering, that I think captures the essence: **a vibrant ecosystem encompassing the roots and soil**